# Why there is no "heroku bundle update"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I don't understand why i have to update my gems localy and push it to heroku, to get the updated version of them?

why there is no `heroku bundle update` command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you `bundle update` or run any of the equivalent CLI commands, I believe Bundler updates your Gemfile.lock file - which keeps a tree of all your gem dependencies - and the lock file is tracked by your git repository ([see here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151495/should-gemfile-lock-be-included-in-gitignore)).

If you were able to run the command directly on Heroku, then you'd have to pull your repository again, otherwise you'd have a git fast-forward issue on your hands.

So really, you're not running any more commands by having to do it locally and push it back up.

Comment: good point, but i still don't like it, its a complex project and i have to do many things before i get the server running and compiling the .lockfile again.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to refine your deploy procedure a little? I know with some of our more complex apps, I'm generally inclined to write a rake task, something like `rake app:deploy`. Which would run through the pre-deploy tasks, run tests and (if passed) then push to heroku.

Answer (score 3):

The real reason why should run bundle update localy first is to test if your application is still working with the newer gem version. heroku bundle update would be a dangerous command.