# Which parts of a Ruby on Rails project should be checked into the repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mercurial

I am setting up a new source control repository for a Ruby on Rails project.  I am using Mercurial and I am wondering which part of my local directory to check in.

The way I have it set up locally in the project workspace is the following file structure:

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 app
drwxr-xr-x 5 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 agenadinik agenadinik  154 2011-04-27 09:58 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x 3 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-29 14:12 db
drwxr-xr-x 2 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 doc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 agenadinik agenadinik  781 2011-05-05 18:57 Gemfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 agenadinik agenadinik 1745 2011-05-05 18:57 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x 3 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 log
drwxr-xr-x 3 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-05-02 17:16 mysql2
drwxr-xr-x 5 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-29 13:17 public
-rw-r--r-- 1 agenadinik agenadinik  264 2011-04-27 09:58 Rakefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 agenadinik agenadinik 9126 2011-04-27 09:58 README
drwxr-xr-x 2 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 script
drwxr-xr-x 7 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 test
drwxr-xr-x 6 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 3 agenadinik agenadinik 4096 2011-04-27 09:58 vendor
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gemfile.lock MUST be checked in!

Ignore

- tmp/
- db/*.sqlite
- public/system/*
- log/*

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should ignore

- tmp/*.*
- db/*.sqlite
- public/assets(system etc - attaches)
- log/*

**EDIT**

**@normalocity wrote:**
Any any file that contains sensitive information (especially if the code repository is in a public place, such as Git). For example, I have an app that stores my SMTP server password in a file so my app can send email. The file that contains that password is NOT included in my repository, however. I secure-copy it by hand if there are changes to the file (which are extremely rare, and obvious when my test suite fails, in my case). – normalocity

Comment: Gemfile.lock MUST be checked in!!

Comment: Any any file that contains sensitive information (especially if the code repository is in a public place, such as Git). For example, I have an app that stores my SMTP server password in a file so my app can send email. The file that contains that password is NOT included in my repository, however. I secure-copy it by hand if there are changes to the file (which are extremely rare, and obvious when my test suite fails, in my case).

Comment: @Aditya Sanghi, you're right, related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151495/should-gemfile-lock-be-included-in-gitignore

Comment: I was actually confused with `Gemfile.lock`. And never learned why I need this. So it is the case when the answering is the studying at the same time :). Thank you @Aditya Sanghi

Answer (score 2):

This is a good guide: http://railscasts.com/episodes/36-subversion-on-rails

You basically want to ignore these files:

- log/*
- tmp/*
- config/database.yml

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3 projects defaults to ignore these files (for Git, but it should be the same for any VCS):

```
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3
log/*.log
tmp/
```

I would recommend that you DO keep your `Gemfile.lock` in your repository. If anyone else is working on the same project, it will guarantee that everyone is working with the exact same versions of each gem. See more [here](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/).