# The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I have spent couple of hours but unable to solve this problem.

When I try to deploy my local rails app to production server using `capistrano` I get the below error:

```
The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

My rails application folder is under version control using Git. I have pushed the local git repo to github and the Gemfile.lock is there on github. So it is under version control. However capistrano continues to give the same error.

Deploy.rb file: https://gist.github.com/brahmadpk/4748991

Comment: I was in same problem. got fix by [adding Gemfile.lock to repo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151540/1090699).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure there is nothing in the releases folder that is not a release. See [this comment on a bundler issue](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1109#issuecomment-1125098) for more details.

This blogpost titled [Capistrano Deployment Trouble](http://www.octolabs.com/posts/2011/4/22/capistrano_deployment_trouble) explains the same issue.

**EDIT TO INCLUDE CONCLUSION FROM DISCUSSION IN COMMENTS**

The `deploy_to` param was not set to an absolute path; hence `capistrano` wasn't able to find the folder to deploy, causing this error message.

Comment: Yes, checked those articles, there is nothing in the releases folder.

Comment: After you added the `deploy.rb file`: Set the `:deploy_to` param to a path. Right now, it is getting set to `fxtofx`. With that, where would capistrano deploy the files to? Set it to an absolute path like `/var/#{application}`.

Comment: Prakash - my application directory is 'fxtofx' on the server. Hence I am using `#{application}`. So the directory structure is fxtofx/releases etc. is there any issue using it that way?

Comment: How is capistrano able to find `fxtofx/releases`? Or for that matter how do you go to `fxtofx/releases `? Shouldn't it be `/fxtofx/releases` or `/usr/fxtofx/releases` or something starting from the root?

Comment: Ok .. I can see what you are pointing out. When I am using `/#{application}`, I am getting an error `mkdir: cannot create directory /fxtofx' `. my linux skills may not be the best.

Comment: Create the base directory (`/fxtofx` or `/var/fxtofx` to follow conventions) manually on the server; and then try deploying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24263/discussion-between-brahmadpk-and-prakash-murthy)

Comment: On my server: `cd ~`, then `mkdir /fxtofx`, I am getting an error of permission denied. Even if I create the directory using sudo, then `deploy:setup` gives the error

Answer (score 14):

Remove `BUNDLE_FROZEN: "true"` from `.bundle/config` file and run `bundle` again.

Comment: This solved it for me, however I had to remove the line from `~/.bundle/config`, which took me a few minutes to find.

Answer (score 4):

I solve this with:

```
set :bundle_gemfile, "your_app_name/Gemfile"
```

in the deploy.rb

Comment: set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') } this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After adding `bundle config unset deployment` this line in the terminal, `bundle install` started working again for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle` and add your `Gemfile.lock` to your version control.

Comment: I can see a Gemfile.lock in my rails directory. As I mentioned in the question my rails directory is under version control. How to add Gemfile.lock specifically?

Comment: It depends on your version control. If you use git run `git add Gemfile.lock` (remove it from your `.gitignore` first if needed).

Comment: Capistrano pulls your app from the remote repository. Did you push your changes before the deploy?

Comment: I am not using github. I have used set :deploy_via, :copy

Comment: You may try `set :copy_strategy, :export`, but I can't see why capistrano won't copy Gemfile.lock if it's tracked by git. The doc says "the SCM checkout command is used to obtain the local copy" (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/copy.rb)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even though I had no files or folders in the releases folder. Turned out it was a silly little thing: the gemfile.lock file in my repo was in **lowercase** for some reason, while capistrano needs Gemfile.lock with a **capital G**.

This is how I solved it:

1. Delete gemfile.lock
2. Delete gemfile.lock from you repo (git rm ...)
3. run `bundle install`
4. add the new Gemfile.lock file to your repo: `git add Gemfile.lock`
5. remove the folders from the server (don't know if this is really needed, did it anyway)
6. deploy

Answer (score -1):

I am getting exactly the same problem.

There is nothing in my releases folder (at all - my deploy cold keeps rolling back).

My gemfile.lock is checked in to Subversion.

I get:

```
** [out :: localhost] The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you   have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.
```

Is there any way to stop the rollback so that I can see what the releases folder looks like at the time it tries to run

```
cd /var/qlarity/releases/20130222003607 && bundle install --gemfile /var/qlarity/releases/20130222003607/Gemfile --path /var/qlarity/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test
```

Later....

I found that I could prevent the rollback by commenting out the code as shown from

```
gems\capistrano-2.14.1\lib\capistrano\recipes\deploy.rb

task :update_code, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  # on_rollback { run "rm -rf #{release_path}; true" }
  strategy.deploy!
  finalize_update
end
```

This enabled me to examine my releases folder and sure enough, there was no Gemfile.lock in it. Turns out I have ended up with an unnecessary folder in my Rails project file structure so that instead of

```
myapp/trunk/app
myapp/trunk/config
...
myapp/trunk/Gemfile
```

I had

```
myapp/trunk/myapp/app
myapp/trunk/myapp/config
...
myapp/trunk/myapp/Gemfile
```

This meant I ended up with a folder containing my Gemfile

```
releases/nnnn/myapp
```

and bundle was looking for Gemfile in

```
releases/nnnn
```

When I changed my Capistrano config from

```
deploy.rb 

set :repository, "file:///D:/_SVN//myapp/trunk"
```

to

```
deploy.rb 

set :repository, "file:///D:/_SVN//myapp/trunk/myapp"
```

now all is good. Really should look at fixing the folder structure next!