# User specific gems with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am using RVM on my server to manage ruby.  I have a gem that is a daemon that I want to run as an unprivileged user, however, when I attempt to do so, I get a permissions error:

```
statusbot@host config]$ statusbot run
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:235:in `rescue in lock': There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that  (Bundler::InstallError)
you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/StatusBot-0.0.4/Gemfile.lock
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:220:in `lock'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:34:in `lock'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:43:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:79:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:91:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

Likewise, I am unable to install gems on a per-user basis:

```
[statusbot@host ~]$ gem install ~/StatusBot-0.0.5.gem 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/StatusBot-0.0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using RVM in multi user mode requires:

1. RVM is installed using `sudo` not `root` user.
2. All users wanting to install rubies / gems must be in the group `rvm` (an extra use case is OSX wher even you are in `rvm` group when checked with `id1` - it could be still not effective for the shell and restart is needed)

The extra use case is **mixed mode** where only parts of RVM are in system and user can create gemsets in `$HOME`, read more about it at RVM site: https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a problem with a gem, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151540/497756 and the followed article http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/ from one of bundler authors `Gemfile.lock` should not be part of the gem.

Try:

```
 sudo rm -f /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/StatusBot-0.0.4/Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: Same error.  The overall issue is due to the fact that non-privileged users cannot install their own gems.  I've edited the question to have more detail about this.