# In Dart and Pub, should I add pubspec.lock to my .gitignore?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Should I add this generated file to my `.gitignore` so that it doesn't show up in my repository?

Should `pubspec.lock` be included in my repository?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This answer has two parts, similarly to the question and answer in [this question about Ruby `bundler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151495/should-gemfile-lock-be-included-in-gitignore).

### Application packages

If you are working on an [application package](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#application-package), then  you should keep the `pubspec.lock` file in your repository as a snapshot of your dependencies.

*From the Pub glossary:*

> Application packages should check their lockfiles into source control,
> so that everyone working on the application and every location the
> application is deployed has a consistent set of dependencies.

### Library packages

However, if you are working on a [library package](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#library-package), then you should not check in the lockfile.

*From the Pub glossary:*

> Library packages should not check their lockfile into source control,
> since they should support a range of dependency versions.

---

See also the [Pub glossary entry for lockfiles](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#lockfile)