# Dart: pub get vs pub upgrade

Tags: dart, dependency-management, dart-pub

According to the [`pub get` docs](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-get.html) the main difference between `pub get` and `pub upgrade` is:

> If a lockfile already exists, pub get uses the versions of dependencies locked in it if possible. If a dependency isn’t locked, pub will get the latest version of that dependency that satisfies all the version constraints. This is the primary difference between pub get and pub upgrade, which always tries to get the latest versions of all dependencies.

But this leaves me with a few questions.

1. What do they mean by "*If a dependency isn't **locked**...*? Locked?!? Like in version control? File system lock? What is this lock of which they speak?
2. Still not clearly understanding the difference between these two commands. Are they saying that `pub get` takes version constraints into account, and that `pub upgrade` doesn't?

Comment: Not sure why, but we've seen `pub get` modify (upgrade) *existing versions* in the lock file. Anyone else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is locked when the `pubspec.lock` file contains an entry for this dependency.
You can change the dependency in `pubspec.lock` manually to specify exactly what version you want to use.
`pub upgrade` checks for the newest version that fits your `pubspec.yaml` configuration and updates your pubspec.lock file automatically.

when `pubspec.lock` is checked in with your package code in a CVS repository you are able to later reproduce the exact same setup as you had when you checked in your code even when your `pubspec.yaml` allowed a wider range of versions for a dependency.

see also

- [Upgrading a dependency](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/#upgrading-a-dependency)
- [In Dart and Pub, should I add pubspec.lock to my .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136739)