# what‘s the best frequence of updating the yarn.lock or package.lock file?

Tags: npm

we are developing an large web application which depend some private npm packages and public packages. we need to lock the version, but we can not sure which time to update these package and update the lock file.

Comment: Try this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552348/should-i-commit-yarn-lock-and-package-lock-json-files/44904494

Answer (score 0):

In my web project, I update lock files only if i add, update, remove a node package for my project. In this case, I take advantage to update all packages of my lock files.

For the other developers who work in my web project, they use cmd :

```
npm ci
```

or

```
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

They must not absolutely modify the lock files.

Furthermore, i am sure that everybody have the same environment (for behavioral reproduction).