# Supporting both `npm` and `yarn` in my project

Tags: node.js, npm

In my project, I maintain support for both `npm` and `yarn`.

At present, whenever I update file `package.json`, I conduct the following process:

1. Delete file `package-lock.json`
2. Delete file `yarn.lock`
3. Delete folder `node_modules`
4. Run `npm install`
5. Delete folder `node_modules`
6. Run `yarn install`

This process seems to guarantee deterministic results for both file `package-lock.json` and file `yarn.lock`.

But on the other hand, it is a little "tedious" to conduct it every time I want to update my project dependencies.

Is there a simple process that I can take instead?

I have read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904494/16004728); it covers this topic pretty well, but not the simplification that I am looking for.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are the benefits of supporting both `npm` and `yarn` for you? It's much easier to enforce the agreement for all project developers to use only one package manager.

Comment: @Anatoly: The benefits are actually described pretty well in the answer that I have linked: `If your project is open-source, the most community-friendly thing to do would probably be to commit both and have an automated process to ensure yarn.lock and package-lock.json always stay in sync`.