# How to have yarn fail on yarn install when package.json and yarn.lock are out of sync?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, lockfile

On a project I have replaced npm with yarn to get the benefits of it, and also enforce our dependencies are locked in via the `yarn.lock`.

Now, a developer added a library with npm@4, which only changed the `package.json`, and not of course the `yarn.lock`.

I would have expected the `yarn install` command to crash on the build server, yet yarn has the--to me unexpected behavior--of adding those libraries in their most current version and then updating the `yarn.lock` on the remote:

```
$ yarn install
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 5.07s.
```

This contradicts yarn's purpose, as the build job does not push the `yarn.lock` back to the repository nor should it.

I want each developer to be responsible of the version they are checking in.

Hence, is there a way to have `yarn install` exit with an error code if the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` are out of sync?

Comment: I opened [an issue on yarn's github repo](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4147)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`--frozen-lockfile`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-frozen-lockfile) parameter:

```
$ yarn install --frozen-lockfile
yarn install v0.27.5
warning ../package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Your lockfile needs to be updated, but yarn was run with `--frozen-lockfile`.
```

This was also recently made clear in the [docs for yarn install](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install):

> `yarn install`
>
> Install all the dependencies listed within package.json
>   in the local node_modules folder.
>
> The `yarn.lock` file is utilized as follows:
>
> - If yarn.lock is present and is enough to satisfy all the dependencies
>     listed in package.json, the exact versions recorded in yarn.lock are
>     installed, and yarn.lock will be unchanged. Yarn will not check for
>     newer versions.
> - If yarn.lock is absent, or is not enough to satisfy
>     all the dependencies listed in package.json (for example, if you
>     manually add a dependency to package.json), Yarn looks for the newest
>     versions available that satisfy the constraints in package.json. The
>     results are written to yarn.lock.
>
> If you want to ensure yarn.lock is not updated, use `--frozen-lockfile.`