# Why does running yarn on windows changes yarn.lock

Tags: yarnpkg

I ran yarn on my project on mac, generated a yarn.lock and committed it to git.

Now I open the same project on a Windows machine, and run yarn to get the dependencies. It outputs

```
yarn install v0.24.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
```

And indeed modifies yarn.lock.

Why does this happen, and what should I do about it?

Note: Windows isn't our main dev environment, we're developing mostly on macs and prod is linux. I'm hesitant to change my dependencies due to a Windows issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the yarn on your system then you need to use the  `--frozen-lockfile` option to prevent the lock file from getting changed.

You can find the issue reported [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4379) and [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3315).