# is it possible to avoid the pubspc.lock file conflct when put it into git version control

Tags: git, flutter

I am writing a flutter app, the `pubspec.lock` file always been conflict after I checked into this file to git version control. I already searching from the web that told me it is better to put the `pubspec.lock` file to version control. [In Dart and Pub, should I add pubspec.lock to my .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136739/in-dart-and-pub-should-i-add-pubspec-lock-to-my-gitignore)

is it possible to avoid the pubspec.lock file conflict? I am delete the `pubspec.lock` file and regenerate it right now because I did not know how to merge the lock file. how about add the `pubspec.lock` to `.gitigore`? I hate to put this file to version control.

Comment: Same thought here but it is good to keep in source control

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on an application package, then you should keep the pubspec.lock file in your repository as a snapshot of your dependencies.

*Application packages should check their lockfiles into source control, so that everyone working on the application and every location the application is deployed has a consistent set of dependencies.*

see more Detail [Glossary of package terms](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#lockfile)

My Suggestion to you not add in .gitigore file.
Thanks You.