# How do I update Gemfile.lock on my Docker host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler

When using Rails inside a Docker container
[several](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-on-docker) [posts](https://blog.codeship.com/running-rails-development-environment-docker/), (including [one on docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)) use the following pattern:

1. In `Dockerfile` do `ADD Gemfile` and `ADD Gemfile.lock`, then `RUN bundle install`.
2. Create a new Rails app with `docker-compose run web rails new`.

---

Since we `RUN bundle install` to build the image, it seems appropriate to `docker-compose build web` after updating the `Gemfile`.

This works insomuch as the gemset will be updated *inside the image*, but:

The `Gemfile.lock` on the Docker host **will not be updated** to reflect the changes to the `Gemfile`. This is a problem because:

1. `Gemfile.lock` [should be in your repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151495/should-gemfile-lock-be-included-in-gitignore/4151540#4151540), and:
2. It should be *consistent* with your current `Gemfile`.

---

So:

How can one update the `Gemfile.lock` on the host, so it may be checked in to version control?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Executing the `bundle` inside `run` **does** update the `Gemfile.lock` on the host:

```
docker-compose run web bundle
```

However: You must still **also** `build` the image again.

Comment: Given this requires two separate commands to be run, I hope there's an alternative answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is the best (only) practical solution I've found as well. I think I'm going to create yet another abstraction by combining `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose run web bundle` in a script file. Hooray abstractions, haha

Comment: This works as long as your Dockerfile follows the format here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ unlike my Dockerfile, which was using a temp `Gemfile` it had stored in `/tmp` - you can check for this issue by running `bundle env` to see where it's getting the Gemfile from.

Answer (score 6):

Just to be clear, the commands to run are:

```
docker-compose run web bundle
docker-compose up --build
```

where *web* is the name of your Dockerized Rails app.

Comment: To update the gemfile.lock i.e to update my gems I need to run `docker-compose run --rm web bundle update` and then `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 4):

***TL;DR*** - make the changes on the container, run bundle on the container and restart for good measure. Locally these changes will be reflected in your app and are ready to test/push out to git, and your production server will use it to rebuild.

## Long; Read:

1. `docker exec -it name_of_app_1 bash`
2. `vim Gemfile` and put something like `gem 'sorcery', '0.9.0'` I feel this ensures you get the version you're looking for
3. `bundle` to get just this version in the current container's `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`

This has been semi normal "Rails" type stuff here, just you are doing it on the container that is running.  Now you don't have to worry about git and getting these changes onto. your git repo because these changes are all happening on your local copy. So like, open a terminal tab and go into your app and `less Gemfile` and you should see the changes.

4. Now you can restart your running container. Your Dockerfile will get rebuilt (in my case by `docker-compose up` locally, tests should pass. Browser test at will.

Commit your changes to git and use your deploy process to check it out on staging.

### Notes:

Check that `Dockerfile` like the OP's links say. I'm assuming that you have some kind of `bundle` or `bundle install` line in your `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1):

Run `bundle update` inside the container, then rebuild.

```
$ docker-compose run web bundle update
$ docker-compose build
```