# Git will not ignore Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, gitignore, gemfile.lock

I have a Gemfile.lock that git simply will not ignore.  It's in my gitignore file (see below) but it keeps showing under unstaged changes whenever I `bundle install`.  Anyone else ever run into something like this?  Thanks in advance.

My Gitignore looks like this:

```
/.tags*
/log
/tmp
/db/*.sqlite3
/public/system
/coverage/
/spec/tmp
**.orig
rerun.txt
Gemfile.lock
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it because the `Gemfile.lock` is already committed to your repository? Is it showing as a new file (with `??` in git status) or a modification (with `M` in git status). If it's the latter then you will need to remove the file with `git rm Gemfile.lock`. Once you commit that change then the file should stop showing up in `git status`.

As an aside, it's generally best practice to keep the `Gemfile.lock` committed to the repository (unless this is a gem). Here's a good SO question about that topic: [Should Gemfile.lock be included in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151495/should-gemfile-lock-be-included-in-gitignore)