# Is the gemfile.lock file needed in a Jekyll site hosted with Github Pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, gemfile.lock, xxe

Lately I've gotten into Jekyll for building documentation sites and hosting them on Github Pages. I understand Github Pages has a very limited list of what is allowed plugin wise. While doing some vulnerability testing I found out the file *Gemfile.lock* is vulnerable to XML External Entity (XXE) Injection.

In my research I've read:

- [Should Gemfile.lock be included in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151495/should-gemfile-lock-be-included-in-gitignore)
- [A Gem's Gemfile.lock should NOT be in source control.](https://github.com/radar/guides/issues/14)
- [Setting up your GitHub Pages site locally with Jekyll](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll)

After reading the accepted answer of:

> Assuming you're not writing a rubygem, Gemfile.lock should be in your repository. It's used as a snapshot of all your required gems and their dependencies. This way bundler doesn't have to recalculate all the gem dependencies each time you deploy, etc.

but I have no control over the Jekyll site. Please correct me if I'm understanding the process but Github Pages builds the site and if the *Gemfile.lock* is for development of Gems and that isn't something I can control it's ok to remove the file and add to the *.gitignore*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub Pages doesn't look for a `Gemfile.lock` file nor the `Gemfile` itself.
All it needs is a proper config file to load gems / plugins.